# Aws Bean Stalk:Nginx redirection is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to use url redirection in nginx but it is not working. When i open url in browser like "/example", it opens default page of beanstalk. But on root tag, my application is working fine.

My nginx configuration

```
server {
    listen   8000;
#    listen   somename:8080;
#    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;


        location / {
                root /opt/myapp;
                index sign-in.html;

        }

    location /example {
                alias /opt/example;
                index index.html;
   }
}
```

if you see in configuration, /example is not working but / is working fine. It is not showing error i have checked logs. so please help why it is not working. I don't have knowledge of beanstalk.

Comment: Where do you want to redirect "www.example.com/example" to?

Comment: If i open /example, then it should get index.html which is located in directory "/opt/example".

Comment: So "www.example.com/example" should redirect to "www.example.com/index.html"?